# Help to identify a unique minifig head

Tags: minifigures, part-identification

I have a minifig head that I can't find on the Brickset website or else where. Not sure where it came from but found it amongst a pile of odd bricks my kids had collected years ago.

[image: minifig head]

The head is probably from before 2002 (last time any of them played Lego). I thought maybe from the Legend of Chima range, but couldn't find it in the sets or minifigs and don't have any other models from that range.

I don't have a figure that might match it but I'm just intrigued to know what it is.

Answer (score 11):

It's one of the Indians from the Western theme, from 1997:
http://brickset.com/minifigs/ww016/Indian-Tan-Shirt-Quiver

Comment: Great, thanks @Huw Millington for the quick id!

Comment: @ken then why not accept the answer